# Laravel Using config() in request validation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using laravel 5.8 and I want to use access global config() in Request validation class but it does not work

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\AppConstant;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class Something extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'url' => 'required',
            'category' => 'in:'.implode(",", config('app.categories').''
        ];
    }
}
```

and here is part of my config/app.php

```
return [

    'name' => env('APP_NAME', 'Laravel'),
    'categories' => [
        'games',
        'entertainment'
    ],
```

but the output is

```
Class App\\Http\\Requests\\Something does not exist
```

```
when i remove config() from request file it works very well
```

Comment: Could be a namespace issue. Try `\config` with the leading slash

Comment: Can you show the value of `config('app.categories')` i.e. what do you get if you do `dd(config('app.categories'));`?

Comment: @RossWilson i get the categories array it works on dd, but not here ```'category' => 'in:'.implode(",", config('app.categories').''```

Comment: your code is missing a close bracket `)` after categories. it should be `'category' => 'in:'.implode(",", config('app.categories')).''`

Comment: @MichaelNguyen hmm, yeah it works now, that was a stupid mistake, Thank you Michael

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your code is missing a close bracket ) after categories. it should be

```
'category' => 'in:'.implode(",", config('app.categories')).''
```